# c# regex replace all patterns with different strings

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace, xor

ok so basically i translated this xor converter from javascript so i can xor strings faster by c+p my c++ code and it just replaces all the strings with xor'd ones for me, but this xors all strings with the first xor it created for the first string any help with this would be greatly appreciated. i tried creating a loop but i just failed and gave up. that is probably what i need to do i just need someone to show me how i should set it up.

```
string Dec2Hex(int test)
    {
        string hex = test.ToString("X");
        return hex;
    }

    string symbols = " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@";
    int toAscii(string xx)
    {
        var loAZ = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        symbols += loAZ.ToUpper();
        symbols += "[\\]^_`";
        symbols += loAZ;
        symbols += "{|}~";
        int loc;
        loc = symbols.IndexOf(xx);
        if (loc > -1)
        {
            //Ascii_Decimal = 32 + loc;
            return (32 + loc);
        }
        return (0);  // If not in range 32-126 return ZERO
    }

    byte[] randByte()
    {
        Byte[] RandByte = new Byte[5];
        new Random().NextBytes(RandByte);
        return RandByte;
    }

    public void RunEncrypter()
    {
        string test = textBox1.Text;
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex x = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\"(.*?)\"", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Singleline);

        var matches = x.Matches(textBox1.Text);
        string s1 = "";

        if (matches.Count <= 0)
            return;

       s1 = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;

        byte[] randombyte = randByte();
        double xvaluestart = randombyte[0];
        string xrefkill = "0x" + Dec2Hex(randombyte[1]) + Dec2Hex(randombyte[2]) + Dec2Hex(randombyte[3]) + Dec2Hex(randombyte[4]);

        int finallen = s1.Length + 1;

        string hexsequence = "\"";
        double xvalue = xvaluestart;
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
        {
            string ch = s1.Substring(i, 1);
            int chval;

            chval = toAscii(ch);
            if (chval == 0) { s1 = "invalid character: " + ch; return; }

            chval ^= (int)xvalue;
            xvalue += 1;
            xvalue %= 256;
            hexsequence += "\\x" + Dec2Hex(chval);
        }
        hexsequence += '"';

        string s2 = "/*" + s1 + "*/XorStr<0x" + Dec2Hex((int)xvaluestart) + "," + finallen + "," + xrefkill + ">(";

        s2 += hexsequence + "+" + xrefkill + ").s";

        textBox1.Text = x.Replace(textBox1.Text, s2);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunEncrypter();
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Please read [mcve] and then [edit] the question to include enough details for us to try and help you.

Comment: Punctuation marks have day-off?

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what you are trying but a simple XOR cipher can be implemented in C# as simple as that:

```
static string Xor(string text, int key)
{
    string result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        int charValue = Convert.ToInt32(text[i]); //get the ASCII value of the character
        charValue ^= key; //xor the value

        result += char.ConvertFromUtf32(charValue); //convert back to string
    }
    return result;
}
```

This algorithm goes through each character in the string, convert it to its integer ASCII value, xor the value with the key, and convert the new value back into a string.